# CMD opens Windows Store when I type 'python'

Tags: python, windows-10, sublimetext3

Today when I tried to run simple code on Sublime Text 3, the following message appeared:

> Python was not found but can be installed from the Microsoft Store: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?linkID=2082640

And when I type Python in CMD, it opens the Windows Store for me to download Python 3.7. This problem started today for no good reason. I didn't change or download anything about Python and already tried reinstalling Python, and the Path environment variable is correct.

Comment: What if you type py from the command line instead of python?

Comment: How about [this solution](https://superuser.com/a/1461471/1061122)?

Comment: I also think, it could be a duplicate to the question referenced by @yellow (it is linked to a specific answer)

Comment: @ChipJust why do I have to type py instead of python all of a sudden?

Comment: @Cagri [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50896496/what-is-the-difference-between-py-and-python-in-the-terminal) has some good information about it, but the short answer is I don't know exactly. It depends on key bindings in your registry on Windows. The Python installer has been putting the py wrapper there instead of python.exe for a while, which is nice because it honors [shebang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shebang).

Comment: how do I disable MS Store from opening, and just print the standard `'python'  is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Answer (score 707, accepted):

Use the Windows search bar to find "Manage app execution aliases". There should be two aliases for Python. Unselect them, and this will allow the usual Python aliases "python" and "python3". See the image below.

[image]

I think we have this problem when installing Python because in a new Windows installation the aliases are in the ON position as in image below. When turned on, Windows puts an empty or fake file named *python.exe* and *python3.exe* in the directory named %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps. This is the alias.

[image]

Then Microsoft put that directory at the top of the list in the "Path" environment variables.

[image]

When you enter "python" in cmd, it searches the directories listed in your "Path" environment variables page from top to bottom. So if you installed Python after a new Windows 10 install then get redirected to the Windows Store, it's because there are two python.exe's: The alias in the App Execution Alias page, and the real one wherever you installed Python. But cmd finds the App execution, alias python.exe, first because that directory is at the top of the Path.

I think the easiest solution is to just check the *python.exe* and *python3.exe* to OFF as I suggested before, which deletes the fake EXE file files.

The first time I ran into this problem, I manually deleted the *python.exe* and *python3.exe* files but when I restarted the files regenerated. That prompted me to search for the App Execution Aliases page and uncheck the box, which solved it for me, by not allowing the files to regenerate.

Based on [this Microsoft Devblog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/python/python-in-the-windows-10-may-2019-update/), they stated they created this system partially for new Python users, specifically kids learning Python in school that had trouble installing it, and focus on learning to code. I think Windows probably deletes those aliases if you install Python from the Windows App Store. We are noticing that they do not get deleted if you manually install from another source.

(Also, the empty/fake python.exe is not really empty. It says 0 KB in the screenshot, but entering "start ms-windows-store:" in cmd opens the Windows App Store, so it probably just has a line with that and a way to direct it to the Python page.)

One alternative, as Chipjust suggested, you can create a new alias for Python using something like DOSKEY as explained in this article for example:
*[How to set aliases for the command prompt in Windows](https://winaero.com/how-to-set-aliases-for-the-command-prompt-in-windows/)*

Another alternative is to delete the user path environment variable that points to the alias files, %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps, but the App Execution Aliases handle more apps than just python, and deleting the path from environment variables breaks all the other apps that have execution aliases in that directory; which on my PC includes notepad, xbox game bar, spotify, monitoring software for my motherboard, paint, windows subsystem for android, to name a few. Also if you think about it, the average Windows user is unfamiliar editing environment variables and on school and business owned computers requires administrative access. So deleting the path to ...\WindowsApps, from the path environment variable, is not ideal.

Comment: I had the same problem.  "App Installer" were both off.  I had to switch them on and off again to stop the problem.

Comment: This answer provides only workarounds. The root cause is that there is "MS made" `python.exe` in a folder listed in the PATH variable. This folder is `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps`. Just make sure your python installation path is listed in the PATH **above** the `WindowsApps`, that's all. This is covered in the user aattk's answer below.

Comment: This was ridiculous that I had to go do this. Why can't Microsoft just leave me alone. I installed Python into a local directory by unzipping it and the command should just work. Just stop!

Comment: I don't get why is this beneficial, could you elaborate on than?

Comment: Yeah I fail to see what's really cool about annoyingly messing with my scripts on various installs of windows too. Consistency goes a long way

Comment: @carlo I tried to make clear why this is beneficial which is mostly for new users, there is more detail in the link I provided as well. Thank you for the constructive feedback.

Comment: woke up this morning to find this problem. 
Suspect windows updated overnight, curr ver 21H1 Build 19043.1165
When I deselected the entries for python and pip, the links in this directory were deleted. (yes I had multiple entries, possibly due to previous installs, uninstalls, upgrades of windows python app)
C:\Users\bmt\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
then attempting python would return this message.
"'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

selecting python again, resulted in cmd > python working again. 
(similarly for pip)

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work immediately. The thing is, I got 2 accounts on my PC. It seems like the aliases from my other account were interfering. I already turned it off on my main account, but the app store was still popping up. When I turned the app aliases off on my other account it worked immediately. Just placing this here if anyone else has the same problem.

Comment: Wtf, why would Windows ever create an alias for python to open windows store???? That shit makes no sense... My PATH variable had the path to python as its first entry, and still windows store opened when I hit python in cmd.

Comment: I would really appreciate if someone will put actual menu location instead of what "search for". My windows is localized :(

Comment: @Krypt click the Windows icon bottom left, then click the gear icon to open Settings, then click Apps: Uninstall, defaults, optional features, then there should be some option in blue text the second line for me is "App execution aliases" which is where you can uncheck the python aliases

Comment: Thanks, the solution worked for me. 1. I Unticked the app execution aliases that pointed to python.exe     2. Add python to path, on above %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps

Comment: Just chipping in to mention that both the Environment Variables and the App Execution fixes were only part of the solution. The only way I could get Python working was to use "py" instead of "python" in CMD. The latter would just error out.

Comment: @CakePrincess The App Execution switch removes the preinstalled Environment Variables, so it is one solution. You wrote it as if they are different solutions. So I wonder what exactly you did with your user & system path variables, did you try to delete manually and then turned the App Executions off? If yes, you may have accidently deleted the wrong path. Or like me, first time I deleted the preinstalled env variables but they regenerated which made me look for the App Executions. If your python installed correct then shouldn't need it but if nothing else works glad at least the alias works.

Comment: there's something ironic about Microsoft, who any other time acts like they are married to backward compatibility (ex: ever tried naming a file/folder "con"?), deciding to break EVERYONE's Python scripts by pointing pointing the top PATH to a dummy executable so that even if you already had Python, it doesn't find the real Python. If this is really about making Python easier to install, what does it matter which Python you use?

Comment: My god this makes it into this years top ten list of Microsoft Moments

Answer (score 43):

This is a PowerShell script that does the magic.

```
Remove-Item $env:USERPROFILE\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python*.exe
```

Answer (score 31):

If the Python interpreter is already installed, then go to *Apps & features* from settings, select Python, and then select modify.

Again select modify and select <kbd>Next</kbd>:

[image: Select next]

Then this window will appear:

[image: Select add Python to environment variable]

Select "add Python to environment variable" and click on the install button. Then again go to apps & features, click modify and click <kbd>Repair</kbd>.
Now go to CMD and type Python.
Problem solved.

Answer (score 29):

The main problem here is that the order in the path calls the windows from top to bottom, and that there is `python.exe` in `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps` which is called first if there are no other `python.exe`s in the `PATH` *above* that line.

To ensure that the correct `python.exe` is called, add the Python interpreter installation folder (containing `python.exe`) to the PATH, above `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps`

#### Here is an example:

- To get to this location, click *"Start"* → start typing "Env" → Select "Edit the system environment variables" → "Environment variables" button → Select the entry for "Path" in the upper list → Click "Edit".

[image]

- Python components should be at the top, as in step 5. If not, move them up by pressing the button in step 6.

Comment: Note that your animated GIF is too large to be uploaded to the Stack Overflow imgr account (limited to 2MB, this image is nearly 10MB). The current hosting option on your own site, is not guaranteed to be stable for the lifetime of your answer (which could easily be *decades*), please find a way to limit its size and then move it to imgr.

Comment: This is actually the correct answer but the negative votes might be from the (previous) animated GIF + language of the printscreen + lack of explanation.

Comment: This is okay, but you'll have to redo it if you ever uninstall/reinstall python or install different versions or distributions of python. Not super difficult, but you could solve this once, permanently, by turning off the alias in Manage app execution aliases page.

Comment: Moving python to the first line in the Path had no effect for me, the Windows Store continued to launch until I followed the execution aliases answer above.

Answer (score 7):

I had problems with this as well, where Windows didn't recognize Python or [Anaconda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaconda_(Python_distribution)) in a double click or cmd (command) prompt.

- Problem: unable to import libraries in "python" cmd in Windows. Instead the Windows "python" cmd took users somewhere they don't want to go.
- Problem Cause: In Windows "Environmental Variables", Windows adds a python.exe and python3.exe (I don't know where these link to) in the "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps" directory.

Solution: I tried deleting the python*.exe files in the WindowsApp directory, but Windows wouldn't allow it, so I opened a command prompt in the "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps" directory and typed:

```
del python.exe
del python3.exe
```

Then I created an environment variable linking to the installed Python interpreter link. In my case, it was C:\Anaconda3; C:\Anaconda3\Scripts, and some others for good measure.

Comment: I followed the aforementioned steps of the preferred answer and I still got the MS store popping up.  Your solution saved my day. Thanks.
By the way, you can use this command to get to that directory:

cd "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps

Answer (score 4):

Because this is a common issue and this appears to be the canonical question, I want to try to give a complete overview of The Python 3.7 Windows Store Fiasco (TM).

### Why is it possible for this to happen?

A convergence of two things: the previous [introduction of the Python Launcher for Windows](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0397/) in 2011 (hereafter `py`), and a Windows 10 update [in May 2019](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/python/python-in-the-windows-10-may-2019-update/) that was apparently intended to make installing Python *easier* for Windows users.

[Oops.](https://dev.to/naruaika/why-i-didn-t-install-python-from-the-microsoft-store-5cbd) Turns out that installation path isn't great; it bypasses the "lengthy" setup wizard... which contains some options that some users find very useful. It caused [other issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56974927/permission-denied-trying-to-run-python-on-windows-10), too. Not to mention that it just works in slightly non-standard ways, [has limitations](https://docs.python.org/3.11/using/windows.html#known-issues) on file system access because it's a Store app, [initially couldn't itself be launched by `py`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/using/windows.html#known-issues)....

### Okay, but why do those factors result in the problem?

Since the introduction of `py`, by default, Windows Python installers do not add the new Python install to the PATH. Why? Because the entire point of `py` is that it uses its own logic to find a Python installation, based on some combination of command-line switches and possibly the source file's own shebang line. Now your source files can be associated with `py` instead of any particular `python.exe`, and you can get Linux-like behaviour when double-clicking a file. Meanwhile, by running `py` at the command line, you have easy access to whatever you need, and you don't have to think about which version of Python was installed most recently. So there's *seemingly* no good reason to put any of those Python installations on the PATH. It only risks confusing you when, for example, the most recently installed version isn't the most up-to-date one. Right?

In the update, Windows 10 put a "python.exe" into a Windows Apps-related folder, which is a wrapper app to open a Microsoft Store link. The idea is that it's on the PATH, but way near the end; so if you have an installed Python, it gets used, and otherwise the wrapper is invoked and helpfully prompts you to install Python - so that you can actually run that random, totally trusted `.py` file your friend sent you on Discord.

And it would work perfectly, if your installed Python were on the PATH.

Oops.

(But, you know, `py` had been introduced around 8 years prior. You'd think someone at Microsoft would have been aware of the potential issue. Maybe instead of a special shortcut link, they could have made an actual script that checks for the presence of `C:\Windows\py.exe` or something.)

### So what are my options?

- You can check the option to add new Python versions to the PATH when you install them, and deal with the fact that `python` at the command line means a specific one of them. If you need to change that, you can manually tweak your PATH variable.
- You can just manually tweak the PATH variable after the fact. (or "Modify" a Python installation to fix it.) This is covered in several other answers.
- Independently of that, you can disable the wrappers, as shown in the top answer. You should probably do this anyway; seeing `python` fail at the command line is less aggravating than dealing with a random GUI window popping up and offering to install something for you, especially when you know you have it already.
- If you want to keep the PATH empty, consider [using virtual environments](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html) for your projects. Whenever a virtual environment is active, the PATH is *temporarily* modified such that `python` means the Python installation of that environment. It's quite convenient, really.
- You might be able to tell your IDEs to use `py` instead of a specific Python installation, and it might even be helpful to do so. I don't know. I don't use one.

Comment: Reading further, it appears that Microsoft and the Python dev team consciously collaborated to get Python into the Store. Which makes it even more mystifying that nobody accounted for this interaction.

Comment: Good to have a summary of events, I was aware of these facts but seeing them gathered will help users who are just starting out with Python on Windows.

Answer (score 3):

As a person who does Python development in Sublime Text, I know you said the Python interpreter path was correct, but when you install the Python interpreter make sure to tick the option to add Python to PATH.

I had the same issue back in the day till I did this.

[image: pythoninstaller.png]

Comment: I checked the box

Comment: Okay, then go to 'Tools' in Sublime Text, 'Build System', then make a new build system and point it to your Python Directory

Answer (score 2):

You can manually add Python to the Windows path by doing this:

1. Start the Run box and enter *sysdm.cpl*

   [image]
2. Go to the *Advanced* tab and click the *Environment Variables* button

   [image]
3. Now you’ll need to locate the relevant Python paths

   Here is how a Python application path looks like:

   [image]

   And this is how a Python Scripts path looks like:

   [image]
4. Select the Path variable, press edit and add both paths (Python application and Python Scripts)

   [image]
5. If it doesn't show, press new instead of edit and fill the New User Variable box

   [image]

   This is how my Variable value looks like:

   C:\Users\Ron\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32;C:\Users\Ron\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts

   [image]

That’s it! You just added Python to the Windows Path.

Source: [Data To Fish](https://datatofish.com/add-python-to-windows-path/)

Comment: I have it added but this does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I have put together a powershell snippet, which reorders WindowsApps and Python folder so that Python is first. Run this as Admin:

```
$appsFld="$env:USERPROFILE\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps"; 
$pyPath=(Resolve-Path "$env:USERPROFILE\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python*\")
$Env:Path = (($Env:Path.Split(';') | Where-Object { $_ -ne "$appsFld" }) -join ';'); 
$Env:Path = (($Env:Path.Split(';') | Where-Object { $_ -ne "$pyPath" }) -join ';'); 
$Env:Path += ";$pyPath";
$Env:Path +=";$appsFld";
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", "$Env:Path", "Machine")
```

Then I can run python just fine:

```
> python
Python 3.10.7 (tags/v3.10.7:6cc6b13, Sep  5 2022, 14:08:36) [MSC v.1933 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> quit
```

Comment: you can also manually go to System Environment Variables menu and press Move Down for the `WindowsApps` line here

Answer (score 1):

This is an additional note for anyone using pyenv-win: after [turning off the application execution aliases](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58773979/85269), run `pyenv rehash`. You may also need to close/reopen your CMD or PowerShell window.

Comment: Why? Could you provide more information about this step?

Answer (score 1):

So, I had the same problem.
My answer was to add python to PATH not only for User variables, it was there, but also for System variables. And now everything works.

[image]

So, I've got the same problem in VENV.
I solved it by typing >> python**.exe**
But to add every time .exe a little bit nervous.

Also try to type python.exe in cmd.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above methods solved my problem.
Let me share my solution with you.

#### Key Fix ( Solution )

Start -> Search -> Type:`cmd` -> Launch

1. See what Python is leading to
   `> where python`
2. You should change the last folder to `PythonXXX`
   `> cd %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312`
3. Add a python3 hard link pointing to the correct python.exe
   `> mklink /H python3.exe python.exe`

#### Investigation

Let's see what's inside PATH

```
C:\Users\user>path
PATH=...omit..
C:\cr5000\Lightning\programs;
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Scripts\;
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\;
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;
```

You can see above python and script are both before WindowsApps. I keep getting python2 and `'import site' failed` when I try to run python with any script.

```
C:\Users\user>python
'import site' failed; use -v for traceback
Python 2.0 (#0, Oct  9 2020, 12:12:52) [MSC 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> ^Z^Z
```

Known facts so far:

1. Alias has been turned off
2. PATH has been added and rearranged

```
C:\Users\user>where python
C:\cr5000\Lightning\programs\python.exe
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\python.exe
```

Aha, there is a sneaky python.exe deep inside another program's folder, this is my unique software conflations situation, and cr5000 is in system PATH, I can't make the user PATH take precedence over the system, so I have to add an python3 alias with symbolic link.

```
C:\Users\user>python3
'python3' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312>mklink /H python3.exe python.exe
Hardlink created for python3.exe <<===>> python.exe

C:\Users\user>python3
Python 3.12.1 (tags/v3.12.1:2305ca5, Dec  7 2023, 22:03:25) [MSC v.1937 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> ^Z^Z
```

So... I finally fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Py is an alias useful for other tasks if you have seveal versions of python. So the **app execution aliases** button unchecking is not recommended. The "new" way to find out the python version installed is typing in CMD

```
py -V
```

Answer (score -5):

Adding a bit to the question. Even when I typed `pip freeze`, it wasn't showing anything.

Here's what I did:
There were multiple instances for the Python application in `/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowApps`.

I deleted those and then it worked.