# Pycharm: Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

This is my environmental variable for the python.[image]I kept getting this error and couldn't figure out why I tried all the other solutions provided online and they are not working at all for me. But the python is working fine when I was using VScode, it is just pycharm that is not working.
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python was not found but can be installed from the Microsoft store (March, 2020)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60842487/python-was-not-found-but-can-be-installed-from-the-microsoft-store-march-2020)

Comment: Thanks but mine is working on VScode, it is pycharm that is printing this error message.

Answer (score 2):

Set python interpreter and create venv environment

[image]

Comment: Thanks now it is working, for some reason, I have two python 3.9 interpreter one of them is working, the other one is not.