# How do I open VS code from iterm2?

Tags: visual-studio-code, iterm2

I'm a Mac user and new to coding.
I want to open VS Code from iterm2. I followed the instruction from an article, but I couldn't open it.

1. I opened VS Code command palette then typed shell.
2. I clicked `Shell Command: install 'code' command in PATH.`
   VS code showed `Shell command 'code' successfully installed in PATH.`
3. I opened my terminal and typed `code .` and my terminal showed:

```bash
code .
/usr/local/bin/code: line 6: python: command not found 
/usr/local/bin/code: line 10: ./MacOS/Electron: No such file or directory
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/141738 - likely an issue with your environment setup. Ensure that you have a working installation of python. For example, in your terminal can you successfully run `python`? If not, probably need to install it. Otherwise sounds like discoverability issues - would try uninstalling and reinstalling python and then vs code and then the code command.  Also try in a native MacOS terminal (rather than iterm2) - if it works there then something related to iterm2's shell profile.

Comment: Also seems like a duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60842487/python-was-not-found-but-can-be-installed-from-the-microsoft-store-march-2020 - although there's unfrotunately no accepted answer there either.

Comment: I installed python about 2 yeasrs ago and used it for a bit then never used it for a while. what I'm trying to do is just following git lessons from youtube :( it's nothing to do with Python. Should I delete the python?

Comment: If you're not able to execute `python` from a terminal, then I'd probably recommend fixing your python installation first - an easy way could just be reinstalling. Otherwise, opening VS Code using the binary is probably not required for whatever git lessons on YT you're trying to do - just open the application as you would any other on MacOS rather than trying to use `code` from a terminal. It's the same - just preference and the actual app probably doesn't rely on python.