# Django manage.py

Tags: python, django, powershell

after creating a new django project

I wrote in powershell(run as administrator):

```
PS C:\Users\User\Desktop\new> python manage.py runserver
```

Then it shows something like this

```
python : Python was not found but can be installed from the Microsoft Store: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?linkID=2082640
At line:1 char:1
+ python manage.py runserver
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Python was not ...linkID=2082640:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

Comment: I think that you need to add python path to System Variables. [the instruction to config python path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-so-it-finds-my-modules-packages)

Comment: I added it to system variables..but still it didn't work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CMD opens window store when I type python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58754860/cmd-opens-window-store-when-i-type-python)

Comment: now a new error occurs which is something like this

Comment: python : Watching for file changes with StatReloader
At line:1 char:1
+ python manage.py runserver
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Watching for fi...th StatReloader:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Comment: Try uninstalling all versions of python and reinstall it?

Comment: Yeah..I tried..didn't work