# Running python script from cmd gives "The syntax of the command is incorrect."

Tags: python, cmd, windows-10

I have a `helloworld.py` containing `print("Hello world!")`.
When I try to run it from the command line with `python helloworld.py` it gives me an error: `The syntax of the command is incorrect.`.

I have python 3.8.2 set up correctly, I get the version when running `python --version` and I can use and print statements in the python interpreter.

So what can I do to fix this problem? I'm running Windows 10.
And I've removed the aliases like suggested in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58773979/8029153

I observe the same behavior in Powershell and `cmd`.

Output with Powershell:

```
PS C:\Users\user> cd .\Desktop\...\scripts\
PS C:\Users\user\Desktop\...\scripts> dir


    Directory: C:\Users\user\Desktop\...\scripts


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        28.4.2020     10.07            188 helloworld.py


PS C:\Users\user\Desktop\...\scripts> python helloworld.py
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

Output with plain `cmd`:

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\...\scripts>dir

 Directory of C:\Users\user\Desktop\...\binaries

28.04.2020  10.08    <DIR>          .
28.04.2020  10.08    <DIR>          ..
28.04.2020  10.07               188 test.py
               6 File(s)      9 696 468 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  135 932 608 512 bytes free

C:\Users\user\Desktop\...\scripts>python test.py
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

Output of Powershell's `get-command`:

```
PS C:\Users\user\Desktop\...\scripts> get-command python

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Application     python.exe                                         0.0.0.0    C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Micros...
```

Output of `where` command:

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\...\scripts>where python
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe
```

Comment: Since it's obviously to late now for getting interesting outputs from the command `python version`, I withdraw my wish to add it here. As I was reported from a Win-10 user "without" a python, the MS Store Python placeholder ignores the `--version` command line switch giving completely empty output (and no errors).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nonsensical combination that the

- Python **interpreter works** and valid
- Python **scripts fail**

can actually only be traced back to an outdated Windows search path.

As to see how the program name typed into the command line is resolved into a runnable binary, use the `where` command. It lists you all matching candidates for all path prefixes (`;`-separated parts) of the `PATH` environment variable.

A look into your actual result

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\...\scripts>where python
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe
```

reveals that python is still resolved to the Windows-Store placeholder named `python.exe` that has the only purpose to install a MS-compilation of Python.

After having installed it (better go to 
https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/
and get an installer there), the value of the `PATH` variable in the old command line window is still the old one, so you could try the above `where` command again and again with no change.

It was not the 3rd install that made it work, but the fact that you tried to run the script in a fresh console window (maybe after a reboot or logoff+login or explorer restart [1]). An [already open command line doesn't see changes to the PATH](https://superuser.com/q/107521/391675) environment variable that are done by the installer.

And the reason why the "Python interpreter worked" must be that you started it (namely *IDLE*) from the Windows start menu.

---

[1] I'm not sure about how exactly the installer added the Python's `bin` directory to `PATH` to make explorer aware of the change, some Installers seemingly manage that, some not, so the restart we often observe at the end of an installation.

Comment: After the 3rd install, it started magically working. So... corruption?

Comment: @IiroAlhonen Finallly I have found a scenario that removes the apparent contradictions. Please let me know if this matches your observations.

Answer (score -1):

Try with this command - `python3 helloworld.py`

Comment: Same error as before.

Comment: If the same error occurs with this command as well, then I guess there are some bugs in the latest version.

Comment: This answer shows that a difference between running `python` and `python3` will be unlikely https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58754860/cmd-opens-window-store-when-i-type-python/58773979#58773979