# 'django' is not recognized as an internal or external command in PyCharm's virtual environment

Tags: python, django, pycharm

New to PyCharm and Django, I've looked through online for this solution for a few hours already, nothing seems to work.

The usual: `python -m django-admin startproject mysite` does not seem to work if my cmd directory is at `C:\Users\...\PycharmProjects\`

On the other hand, if I use `cd C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts`
before reentering the former code, I get the exact results that I want.

Any idea how to fix this?

Edit:
Okay, so I figured a solution. If I were to copy "django-admin.exe" into `C:\Users\...\PycharmProjects\`, `django-admin startproject mysite` will work as intended.

The real issue I have is the command `python -m` itself. Nothing that follows after that line seems to work with it. I've revised my advanced environment pathing, but so far I haven't had much luck.

Edit 2:
Typing `python` takes me to Windows Store, but `py` will work as intended. Subsequently, problems like `py -m django --version` will work as intended if I type them in cmd. However, the problem persist if I try to do it in my PyCharm virtual environment.

I've tested and changed multiple directories for both cmd and PyCharm's virtual environment, the solution works consistently in cmd, but not in Pycharm. Any explanations for this?

Comment: Very specific to your local env

Comment: Have you looked at [this page in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/faq/troubleshooting/#command-not-found-django-admin)?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add python to your system path variable [this is a quick tutorial on how to do so](https://datatofish.com/add-python-to-windows-path/)

Comment: I followed exactly the instructions of the link that you've gave me, but the problem is still not resolved.

Comment: Try to run `django-admin startproject mysite` without `python -m`

Comment: Didn't work either. For some reason my `python -m` command is really screwed. `pip show django` works fine in cmd, but `python -m django --version` doesn't.

Comment: Can you open the python shell in cmd ? By simply typing python

Comment: Typing `python` as itself takes me directly to microsoft store. No response if I typed `python -`. I've edit my question above a little. Thanks for staying with me for so long.

Comment: Your path variable should point to where python is installed .. since runing python by itself doesnt work that means it is a path variable problem because you can not run python outside of the installation folder

Comment: This is getting more and more confusing. `python` takes me to windows store, but `py` would work as intended. Consistent with this page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58754860/cmd-opens-window-store-when-i-type-python Now if I were to run `py -m django --version` in cmd, it will also work as intended, but if I try running that in PyCharm's virtual environment, it stops working.

Comment: I'm sorry i dont use pycharm as my ide so i dont know much about it