# Typing python in CMD opens up the Microsoft store download for Python 3.8

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is fairly new problem I just got. I have Python 3.78 installed and it was working perfectly fine yesterday, but now when I type python in CMD without any notification or message opens up the Microsoft store and prompts me with a Python 3.8 download. I have batch script that runs my python file and I saw it getting no results and that's when I found out. Am I supposed to install Python 3.8 now or can I just keep using 3.7?

Comment: *I type python in CMD*? You mean in a Command Prompt window? It sounds like there is something wrong with your path settings. There is no urgent need to upgrade to 3.8 right now. You can do that whenever you're ready to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can use a old version of python, you can use a 2.x version also which is much older. It sounds like python has been removed from your PATH or got uninstalled.

Try add your python installation to the PATH and it should work again:
[Set python path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-so-it-finds-my-modules-packages)

**Update**:
Windows have added app execution aliases for the python keyword, see below answer for more details and how to solve it
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58773979/5719145

Comment: I tried re-installing Python 3.78 to path and still had issue. Moving up to 3.83 fixed the problem but I'm still wondering why It did that.

Comment: Updated the answer, probably you had an windows update which added the aliases. You Executed it and when doing the installation Windows removed the execution aliases for you therefor it works now. It is explained better by others.