# Autoformatting failed, buffer not changed : Sublime text

Tags: sublimetext3, python-3.8, autoformatting, sublime-anaconda

While setting up Python Development Environment in Sublime text 3, I wanted Auto formatting on and hence I made the following settings in Preferences > Package settings > Anaconda > Settings User

```
{
    "auto_formatting": true,
    "autoformat_ignore":
    [
    ],
    "pep8_ignore":
    [
        "E501"
    ],
    "anaconda_linter_underlines": false,
    "anaconda_linter_mark_style": "none",
    "display_signatures": false,
    "disable_anaconda_completion": true,
    "python_interpreter": "/usr/local/bin/python3"
}
```

The auto_formatting value is set to true in user settings and it is set to false in default settings .
The  auto formatting does not work out and gives me  **Autoformatting  failed, buffer not changed** error . Also tried changing **auto_formatting_timeout = 5** //seconds , but that **didn't work out** . It would be of great help if someone could help me out .

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same issue. The problem is the last line is pointing to the wrong path for your python interpreter

```
Preferences > Package Settings > Anaconda > Settings - User

Delete the last line   
"python_interpreter": "/usr/local/bin/python3"

Replace it with  
"python_interpreter": "C:\\Users\\YOUR_NAME\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\python.EXE"
```

IMPORTANT: Your python interpreter path might be different to mine so find out where it is. Remember you need to use TWO backslashes in the path not ONE

Answer (score 0):

Sublime is looking for `python` in environmental variable when you build it, and it is not able to find it there. You can test it in cmd by typing `python` and if it opens Microsoft store then here is the fix you can do, it worked for me. Open setting -> search for `manage app execution aliases` -> turn off "python.exe" and "python3.exe". Now check if you can get `python` in cmd by typing `python`, if you do then sublime problem should be fixed. If you want to know why this works follow this [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58754860/cmd-opens-window-store-when-i-type-python)