# Python command shows no output

Tags: python, console, command, output

I have python 2.7.18 installed. However when typing python commands, it shows no output. I have added Python27 as well as C:/Python27/Scripts added to the path.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1082] (c) 2019 Microsoft
Corporation. All rights reserved.

 
C:\Users\yasht>python --version
 
C:\Users\yasht>

C:\Users\yasht>python get-pip.py

C:\Users\yasht>
```

Comment: Does just `python` open the store? Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58754860/cmd-opens-window-store-when-i-type-python) fix if it does.

Comment: Can you tell your PC specs

Comment: By the way just type `python` does that works

Comment: @Carcigenicate It did not open the store. However still following the solution for the same helped solve the problem. Thanks mate !

Comment: @Uncias Solved the problem. Had to turn off App installer for python.exe from App execution Aliases

Comment: @yashthakkar Odd, but glad it worked.