# (vsc) every python command prints Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-3.9

I recently deleted python 3.8.2 and installed python 3.9.
But when I use the `python` command on visual studio code, Microsoft shop opens and if I do something like `python -v` it prints Python.(It works well on console)

How can I fix this?
[image]

Comment: What do you mean the python command in vsc?

Comment: entered an image showing the problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CMD opens window store when I type python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58754860/cmd-opens-window-store-when-i-type-python)

Comment: This problem only happens on vsc

Comment: That's interesting, are you using `cmd` or `powershell` ?

Comment: I think visual studio code uses Powershell but on my Powershell or cmd, it works

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224772/discussion-between-burning-alcohol-and-kiki7000).

Comment: Glad it helped, maybe you can try to leave an answer down below and help others too!

Comment: I just restarted the computer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per our discussion, the golden rule is ***always try to restart your computer first***.

If that does not work, see [how to fix this by setting alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58754860/cmd-opens-window-store-when-i-type-python).