# VSCode not selecting the correct python interpreter

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have a script that I need to run using a very specific python interpreter in my hard drive.
I am using vscode as the IDE and trying to select the python interpreter using the command palette.
[image: Vscode]

However, since the concerned interpreter is not present, I manually search it.
[image: Searching]

However, even after that, it doesn't work as typing python in the terminal then opens the windows store for installing a python IDE. I also tried adding the interpreter's path to the environment variables but the problem still persists.

How do I solve this issue.
Thank You for the help.

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom left you can select the Python interpreter.

Here it shows you on -how to do that: [Python Interpreter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sigr9.png)

Answer (score 0):

The Python version you selected on VS Code only effects the editor. Right click to any file on the sidebar and select `Open in Integrated Terminal`. If your selected Python version is created with virtualenv it will activated and your `python` command works.

If not worked and you want a global Python version, you need to add Python path to your system variables to work `python` command. Check this:
https://geek-university.com/python/add-python-to-the-windows-path/

Btw I don't think your python.exe in FreeCad/bin directory is proper Python version

Answer (score 0):

**Reason:**

Your system environment path contains this: `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps`.

**Solution:**

Open `Window Search`(Win) to find `Manage app execution aliases`. To turn off App Installer of python3 like this:

[image]

You can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58773979/13037676) for more information.