# Pycharm : Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I was trying to get Django installed onto my Pycharm.

In Terminal, I typed in

> python -m pip install Django

When I pressed enter on the information,

It told me:

Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.

I already have Python installed and put it as the base interpreter for the file. Not sure why Pycharm wants me to install it from the Microsoft store???

Please help!

Comment: Can you check whether you configure python interpreter. If not please follow this url and check it out **https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CMD opens Windows Store when I type 'python'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58754860/cmd-opens-windows-store-when-i-type-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either search for the exe und run it like `{pathtoexe}/python.exe -m pip install Django` or try `python3`instead of `python`. In addition to that you can check your path variables where you should find the actual command.