# Command "python" in vscode terminal opens microsoft store but is working in external powershell, Windows

Tags: python, powershell

I recently switched from mac to windows so I have to reinstall python. I installed it with "Add Python 3.10 to PATH" checked and a custom location of C:\Python310. It works in powershell but opens the Microsoft store when typed in the vscode terminal. [image]

How do I fix this?

Comment: See if the path env variables match. Run ` $env:path -split ';' | sort ` in VSCode termnal and compare that output to one in your ordinary Powershell session.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CMD opens Windows Store when I type 'python'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58754860/cmd-opens-windows-store-when-i-type-python)