# How to execute podman-compose from a windows command line?

Tags: podman-compose

I have replaced "Docker Desktop for Windows" with Podman and Podman Desktop. I also installed podman-compose. podman and podman-compose run fine on the WSL command line (I installed an Ubuntu distro).
I can also execute "podman" on the Windows command line (in both, cmd and PowerShell). However, "podman-compose" is not recognized as a command.

What is required to also be able to execute "podman-compose" on the Windows command line? I googled around but all instructions I found seem to assume that one executes that in a shell in WSL.

Is this possible at all? I can imagine that passing the current Windows path to the shell in WSL and other details may be a bit of a problem...

Addition - response to @mre (below):

Thanks for the instructions. I executed them. The first three lines went OK, but the last one yields:

```
(venv-podman) C:\Users\mmo>podman-compose --version
podman-compose version: 1.0.6
['podman', '--version', '']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\mmo\venv-podman\Scripts\podman-compose.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\mmo\venv-podman\lib\site-packages\podman_compose.py", line 2941, in main
    podman_compose.run()
  File "C:\Users\mmo\venv-podman\lib\site-packages\podman_compose.py", line 1406, in run
    self.podman.output(["--version"], "", []).decode("utf-8").strip()
  File "C:\Users\mmo\venv-podman\lib\site-packages\podman_compose.py", line 1098, in output
    return subprocess.check_output(cmd_ls)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 420, in check_output
    return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
  File "C:\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 501, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "C:\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 969, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 1438, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

(venv-podman) C:\Users\mmo>
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that the issue running python scripts (and podman-compose apparently is just a python script) was a brain-damaged feature in Windows, namely two "Windows execution aliases" that - for whatever reason - were defined on my system. When calling "python" on the command line this opened the Windows Store offering to download and install python instead of actually starting Python (which I had already installed via the normal installer).

It puzzled me enormously why entering "python" would bring up the windows store even though the Python install directory was on the path. I finally found an explanation for that "phenomenon" and a solution how to remove that garbage here: [CMD opens Windows Store when I type 'python'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58754860/cmd-opens-windows-store-when-i-type-pythonv)
Removing/disabling this "alias" also fixed the issue with podman-compose...

Answer (score 4):

Basically it's the same process as installing "podman-compose" into WSL (or any other Linux distro):

1. Install Python for Windows: https://www.python.org/downloads/
2. Create a virtual environment and install "podman-compose":

   ```
   C:\somedir> python.exe -m venv venv-podman
   C:\somedir> venv-podman\Scripts\activate.bat
   (venv-podman) C:\somedir> pip install podman-compose
   (venv-podman) C:\somedir> podman-compose --version
   ```

You can now call `podman-compose` from all other directories, because it was put into your search path by `activate.bat`.

If you exit this CMD (Windows Command Prompt), you just have to execute the second step again (e.g. calling `activate.bat`).

**Update:** This is the whole input and output on the shell:

```
D:\>C:\Python310\python.exe -m venv venv-podman

D:\>venv-podman\Scripts\activate

(venv-podman) D:\>pip install podman-compose
Collecting podman-compose
  Using cached podman_compose-1.0.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (34 kB)
Collecting pyyaml
  Using cached PyYAML-6.0-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (151 kB)
Collecting python-dotenv
  Using cached python_dotenv-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
Installing collected packages: pyyaml, python-dotenv, podman-compose
Successfully installed podman-compose-1.0.6 python-dotenv-1.0.0 pyyaml-6.0
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.2.3; however, version 23.1.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'D:\venv-podman\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

(venv-podman) D:\>podman-compose --version
podman-compose version: 1.0.6
['podman', '--version', '']
using podman version: 4.5.1
podman-compose version 1.0.6
podman --version
podman version 4.5.1
exit code: 0

(venv-podman) D:\>
```

**Concerning the updated post (python stacktrace):** Is `podman.exe` in your path? `podman --version` should ouput your podman version - regardless of whether you are in the venv or not. After installing Podman Desktop, this should be in your path.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work. Since I weren't able to append my screen output into a comment I added it as addition to the question. Please see above.

Comment: Can you be more precise about what exactly did not work? Which step, which error?

Comment: I had added the commands and their output in the mentioned "addition". All calls to podman-compose yield that exception re. a missing file (see stacktrace above)

Comment: Please ensure that podman.exe is in your path. I updated my answer above.

Comment: It was already. The reason turned out to be something different - see my own answer. Thanks for helping!

Comment: Just for completeness, installing python from Microsoft Store did not work for me. I had to install it from the https://www.python.org/downloads/ installable (s the post already points out).