# Why does running this python program from Terminal fail?

Tags: python, path, sys

So, I wrote a basic script:

```
import sys

if len(sys.argv) != 3:
    print(0)
else:
    arg1 = int(sys.argv[1])
    arg2 = int(sys.argv[2])
    print(arg1 + arg2)
```

But when I try to do `python3 test.py 1 2` it fails with exit code 1 and just prints "Python"
In my path I have C:\Users\filip\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311

However, if I run `C:\Users\filip\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe test.py 1 2` it works fine and prints "3".

I tried changing the Path but this doesnt seem to work...

Comment: Maybe it is the [fake windows-store python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58754860/cmd-opens-windows-store-when-i-type-python). What does `gcm python -All` and `gcm python3 -All` return when executed in powershell? Please add it to the post.

Comment: Actually it was it, thanks!